# Окргуление до десятых в php

Tags: php, калькулятор

подскажите пожалуйста, как округлить полученный результат до десятых?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Калькулятор</h1>
        <form action="input.php" method="get">
            <label for="x1"></label>
            <input type="text" name="x1" id="x1">
            <label for="operation">
        <select name="operation" id="operation">
            <option value="+">+</option>
            <option value="-">-</option>
            <option value="/">/</option>
            <option value="*">*</option>
        </select>
            <label for="x2"></label><input type="text" name="x2" id="x2">
            <input type="submit" value="Посчитать">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

    <?php
// проверяет массив на пустоту
if (empty($_GET)) {
    return 'Ничего не передано!';
}

// проверяем через функцию пустой метод гет с массивом операция 
if (empty($_GET['operation'])) {
    return 'Не передана операция';
}

if (($_GET['x1'] == '') || ($_GET['x2'] == '')) {
    return 'Аргументы не переданы';
}

// создали переменные, в которые поместили значения из GET-запроса
$x1 = intval($_GET['x1']);
$x2 = intval($_GET['x2']);

$expression = $x1 . ' ' . $_GET['operation'] . ' ' . $x2 . ' = ';

// проверка на то чтобы пользователь мог записовать только числа
if (!is_numeric($x1) || !is_numeric($x2)) {
    return 'x1 и x2 должны быть числами';
}

switch ($_GET['operation']) {
    case '+':
        $result = $x1 + $x2;
        break;
    case '-':
        $result = $x1 - $x2;
        break;
    case '*':
        $result = $x1 * $x2;
        break;
    case '/':
        if ($x2 === 0) {
            return 'На ноль делить нельзя';
        } else $result = $x1 / $x2;
        break;
    default:
        return 'Операция не поддерживается';
}

return $expression . $result;


<?php
    $result = require __DIR__ . '/calc.php';
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Калькулятор</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        body{
        background: #A0C1B8;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #351F39;
    }

    .container{
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #fff;
        width: 500px;
        text-align: center;
        height: 150px;
    }

    h1{
        font-size: 36px;
        font-family: monospace;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1>Результат вычислений:</h1>
        <?= $result ?>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.round.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция round() первым параметром принимает число для округления, а вторым - количество символов после запятой.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.round.php

В вашем случае будет так:

```
return $expression . round($result, 1);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!

Comment: @Matc, Если ответ Вам помог, то пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый (галочка слева от ответа).